# Pyglet/OpenGL image flickering on mouse movement

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

I was following the ["Pyglet Python and OpenGL - part 01 - Hello Triangle"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wyv5TnkFuxE) tutorial by [Attila Toth](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4L3JyeL7TXQM1f3yD6iVQQ) on YouTube to draw a triangle with Pyglet, as I have never used Pyglet before. As far as I know, the code is identical to what is in the video, however when I move my mouse the image flickers, but there are no error messages.

For reference, my computer has 4 gigabytes of RAM, an i3 7020U and integrated graphics, with DirectX version 12. I am using Windows 10 build 18632.

The code:

```py
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *
class Window(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.set_minimum_size(400, 300)

        self.triangle = Triangle()

    def ondraw(self):
        self.triangle.vertices.draw(GL_TRIANGLES)

class Triangle():
    def __init__(self):
        self.vertices = pyglet.graphics.vertex_list(3, ('v3f', [-0.5,-0.5,0.0, 0.5,-0.5,0.0, 0.0,0.5,0.0]),
            ('c3B', [100,200,220, 200,110,100, 100,250,100]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Window(800, 600, "The Game", resizable=True)
    window.ondraw()
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce the issue, there's no flickering on my machine. *(GTX 1070, i7 from 6 years ago and 16GB of RAM, windows 10, etc)*

However, there are some minor issues with your code.
For one, it's `on_draw` not `ondraw`, which will become important later on as it's a hook-override for [pyglet.window.Window.on_draw](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/window.html#pyglet.window.Window.on_draw) function which gets called at certain events.

And another important function here is to set the `glViewport` otherwise nothing will show on the screen. So the minimal code you need, is this:

```py
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *
class Window(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.set_minimum_size(400, 300)

        self.triangle = Triangle()

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.triangle.vertices.draw(GL_TRIANGLES)

    def on_resize(self, width, height):
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height)

class Triangle():
    def __init__(self):
        self.vertices = pyglet.graphics.vertex_list(3, ('v3f', [-0.5,-0.5,0.0, 0.5,-0.5,0.0, 0.0,0.5,0.0]),
            ('c3B', [100,200,220, 200,110,100, 100,250,100]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Window(800, 600, "The Game", resizable=True)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

It's very important to understand that the `on_***` events are triggered by internal mechanics of Pyglet, not something you should call manually (as you did in your `if __name__ ...` by doing `window.ondraw()`), it's not a good idea.

Instead, if you want to force a `draw` event, simply trigger it by triggering a Pyglet event, some examples are:

- Mouse movement
- Keyboard input (try hitting spacebar)
- Setting a clock/timer to schedule updates

The flickering probably comes from your graphics card (or lack of proper driver) which simply can't handle the refresh-rate you're demanding of it. Try hitting <kbd>space bar</kbd> a couple of times really fast, that probably causes the flickering too. In which case, you probably won't get the performance out of that machine that you're expecting.

A workaround could be: [batched rendering](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/graphics.html#batched-rendering) which significantly improves rendering times, altho, for a simple triangle you shouldn't experience problems already.